# Authorization control in redirected page in php

Tags: php, redirect, authorization

I have a simple controller which shows confirmations to be approved.When the users press register button confirmation page is shown.

But when users enter url as ..../confirmation  without registering , the page is shown. I dont want it to be shown without registering.

in asp.net mvc4 this can be done with ChildActionOnly anotation.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the session started:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

OK, this seems to be quite simple - after registration, and before you redirect a user to the confirmation page, do something like this (this is **pseudo-code** naturally). Let's say the $user->registered() returns TRUE/FALSE as a result of registration, and $user->hasConfirmedRegistration() returns TRUE/FALSE as a result of reistration confirmation. So you should do something like:

```
//this should be in your registration controller/function, i.e. /users/register
if ($user->registered()) {
   $_SESSION['showConfirmation'] = TRUE;
}
```

Then you should put this in the beggining of your function, to prevent showing your confirmation page to non-registered users.

```
//This should be in your confirmation controller/function, 
//i.e. /users/confirm_registration:

//if user has not registered, do not show the page
if (! $_SESSION['showConfirmation']) {
   header('Location: /'); // redirect to main page
   return;
}

// -- enter code that handles storing confirmation, handling $_GET/$_POST etc. --

//then unset session variable, which is no longer needed
if ($user->hasConfirmedRegistration()) {
   unset($_SESSION['showConfirmation']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand what you're trying to achieve without seeing your code. But it sounds like you dont want someone to beable to access a specific page without performing an action first.

Something like this might help you.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(somesessionamehere)){
header("location:form.php");
}
?>
```

Register a session when the user submits the form, then when they go to that page it checks to see if the session is registered. If it isn't then it redirects to the previous page.

Have a look at this URL for a login based example: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to check, on your confirmation page, that the user has just send registration data.

For example, if you have an input field named "login" in your form, you can check the presence and value of "login" in either `$_REQUEST`, `$_POST` or `$_GET`, depending on your form "method" attribute. If it's not there, the form has not been posted and you can assume that the user just entered the URL. You can redirect him to the login page.

```html
<form method="post" action="/confirmation">
    <input type="text" name="login" />
    [...]
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```php
<?php
if (!isset($_POST["login"])) {
    // redirect
    header("HTTP/1.0 302 Found");
    header("Location: /login");

    return;
}

// show confirmation
// [...]
```